# How may I mount a disk with a Apple / Mac partition table (APM) in Linux?

Tags: partitioning, linux-kernel, osx-leopard, debian-wheezy, sata-to-usb

I've backed up some files from a old Powerbook G4 (AluBook), and I used the Mac Partion manager or whatever to first initialize the disk.

It worked, originally, as one large volume, and I copied several files to it.  The disk probably has files from 1-2 pre-existing Windows installation on it.

## first 2 512b blocks

Here is what the first 2 blocks look like, dumped out into Bash

```
ER���@x$����"��PM?AppleApple_partition_
```

Using Debian GNU/Linux I see a strange assortment of partitions, not just the one large folder like in an old Mac.  (Currently it doesn't read in any Macs either, although it did at least once before).

**I would love to mount this drive into Debian, and copy the files!**

I have installed all packages related to HFS+, as these probably are needed.

## parted

gives me this data...

I am expecting one large drive, 160GB, with about 31GB of data on it
(not what is shown below):

```
(parted) unit b                                                           
(parted) p                                                                
Model: ST916082 3AS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 160041885696B
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: mac

Number  Start          End            Size          File system  Name                      Flags
 1      512B           32767B         32256B                     Apple
 2      32768B         61439B         28672B                     Macintosh
 3      61440B         90111B         28672B                     Macintosh
 4      90112B         118783B        28672B                     Macintosh
 5      118784B        147455B        28672B                     Macintosh
 6      147456B        409599B        262144B                    Macintosh
 7      409600B        671743B        262144B                    Macintosh
 8      671744B        933887B        262144B                    Patch Partition
10      135151616B     91240419327B   91105267712B  hfs+         Apple_HFS_Untitled_1
11      91240419328B   91777290239B   536870912B    hfs+         Apple_HFS_Untitled_2
13      91911507968B   113693339647B  21781831680B  hfs+         Apple_HFS_Untitled_3
14      113693339648B  113727942655B  34603008B     hfs+         Apple_HFS_Untitled_4
16      113862160384B  160041877503B  46179717120B  hfs+         Apple_HFS_Untitled_5
```

Comment: I found a really helpful starting tip [http://superuser.com/a/592848/351727] from @Spiff about the different types of file system headers.

Comment: I've creaetd [https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148949/is-this-a-so-called-hybrid-mbr-partition-table-and-how-can-i-mount-this-is-li] to help solve the problem:  Issue is probably that here is a so-called hybrid-MBR, or whatever was created by the specific Mac OS on the old G4; and this is a non-uefi setup and needs to be modified before almost any system will read it.  I'll update here as time allows.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because [it was cross-posted to Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/148949/108618); already answered, the answer is long accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it could work with darling-dmg, it can read rather modern Apple_partition_map :

```
sudo apt-get install libfuse-dev cmake
git clone https://github.com/darlinghq/darling-dmg
mkdir darling-dmg-build && cd darling-dmg-build
cmake ../darling-dmg
./darling-dmg disk_afs.bin mount_dir/
```

If it's not working, the source code is fairly readable, maybe you can patch it for your needs.